# Is it possible to use Jenkins secret as an imagePullSecret in Kubernetes pod agent template in declarative pipeline

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

My goal is to set up jenkins agent pod in kubernetes cluster for which the docker image is needed to be pulled from a private registry. I cannot provide the credentials in source control. Is there any possible way to fetch credentials from jenkins secrets rather than providing a kubernetes secret in podSpec?

Answer (score -1):

I've done this before when the images were stored in Azure Container Registry (ACR). In that case we used the "with credentials" plugin combined with the "Azure CLI" plugin to push/pull the images from ACR.

Here is a similar example, but using docker hub instead of ACR as the private registry:
https://medium.com/@gustavo.guss/jenkins-building-docker-image-and-sending-to-registry-64b84ea45ee9

Comment: My doubt is in the agent directive, how can we pass the docker registry credentials stored in the jenkins secret?

Comment: The pod spec I use is: `    agent { 
        kubernetes {
            yaml """
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: jenkins
spec:
  containers:
  - name: dreddAgent
    image: xyz.azurecr.io/dredd:v9.0.3
    imagePullPolicy: Always
"""
        }
    } `

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of the `imagePullSecret` value? Is it the about the credential when pulling the `jenkins` image from a private repo?